# div will not shrink in chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am trying to get `#container1` to shrink when it matches the parent divs height. I was able to get this to work in firefox with a flex container, but in chrome, the `<div>` won't shrink past the height of the inner content kind of breaking the rest of the layout.

```css
#grid-wrap {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container1 {
  background: aqua;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

#container2 {
  background: beige;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-wrap">
  <div id="grid">
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="container1">
        short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block of text short block
        of text short block of text short block of text short block of text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
      long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long
      block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long
      block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long
      block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long
      block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text long block of text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of exact output do you want?

Comment: I was looking for the smaller div to become scrollable when the height of the page got too small. I was able to get it to work after updating my browser, I think there was just something wrong with my computer.

Comment: I tested in firefox and chrome, and it works well.